# Intel AX200 wifi on Thinkpad Extreme in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, kernel-modules, thinkpad, iwlwifi

I'm unable to use wifi in Arch Linux on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme (Gen 2). I verified that the Intel AX200 network interface works through windows. I'm accessing the local network (and the internet through it) via a wired network connection.

I'm running Linux version 5.5.9-arch1-2 (linux@archlinux) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1))

The systemd journal holds this info:

```
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
systemd-udevd[438]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-cc-a0-39
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-cc-a0-52
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Furthermore, `ip link` only shows the loopback and the wired nic.

When I look into the NetworkManager systemd logs, there seems to be at least an attempt to use the wifi:

```
manager[0x557825231080]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
manager[0x557825231080]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
manager[0x557825231080]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Loaded device plugin: NMOvsFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-ovs.so)
Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/1.22.10-1/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
manager: Networking is enabled by state file
```

Running `rfkill list` only yields this:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Edit:
BIOS Info

- UEFI BIOS Version N20ET42W (1.29)
- UEFI Bios Date 2020-01-20
- Embedded Controller Version N20HT34W (1.21)
- ME Firmware Version 12.0.47.1524
- Machine Type Model 20QVCT01WW
- Wireless Auto Disconnection Disabled

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing the `linux-firmware` package.